# "Fuzzily" open a file in vim from the command line

Tags: vim, fuzzyfinder

I've been using the [FuzzyFinder](https://github.com/vim-scripts/FuzzyFinder) plugin for Vim for a couple weeks and I'm really enjoying it so far. The one thing I do find annoying is that all those fuzzy-finding benefits are only available *after* Vim is already open.

Is there a way to fuzzy-find a file from the command line, rather than typing out the whole path?

Comment: That seems to be more of a shell feature, try Zsh it has that behavior by default.

Comment: Okay, perfect. I'm already using Zsh; do you know off the top of your head how to use that behavior? Googling for `zsh fuzzy matching` isn't showing anything too promising so far.

Comment: For me it works just by hitting TAB, it's not the exact same behavior but it's pretty similar. For instance if I just type D*op, it expands to Desktop if I'm in my HOME folder when I hit TAB, it's been a while since I edited my zshrc though so I'm not sure.

Comment: You might have to add `autoload -Uz compinit; compinit` to your `~/.zshrc` to get all the completion stuff working.  Its fuzzy matching isn't going to be exactly like FuzzyFinder's, but there are some handy features.  One example: you can do something like `vim s/p/f<TAB>` and it will expand `src/projects/foo`, assuming there are no ambiguous matches.

Comment: Okay, I see the `s/p/f<TAB>` thing and that's pretty cool. Not exactly the same thing, but still pretty cool.

Comment: What I was hoping for was something like `vim -f somestring` that would open `path/to/file_containing_somestring.foo`.

Comment: How would that scipt decide if you want `file_containing_somestring.foo` and not `other_file_containing_somestring.foo`? How would it show that there are other matches? How would it show you those other matches?

Comment: I was guessing that maybe it would do those things by opening Vim or something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can start Vim with FuzzyFinder pre-populated:

```
vim -c ":FufFile somefilepattern"
```

Then you only need to select the file from the control.

Comment: This seems very close to what I want, thanks. If I type `vim -c ":FufFile **/somefilepattern"`, it works, but I have to hit the right arrow key until I get to the end of `somefilepattern` and then start typing in order for FuzzyFinder to kick in. Am I missing something?

Comment: I'll select your answer even though it's not 100% working for me. Whatever my particular issue is, your answer is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with zsh, check this [demo](http://shelr.tv/records/512624c6966080252e00006f)